# Git-Flow and dependencies

Tags: git, git-flow

We're running into a strange case with, specifically with Git-Flow and I'm wondering how other developers have solved this. So here's the issue:

Dev 1 is working on `feature/thing` 
Dev 2 is working on `feature/different-thing`

These are independent features, but `feature/different-thing` is going to make changes to the API that, once released, would break stuff in `feature/thing` until it all gets merged.

So my question is this: if `feature/different-thing` finishes first...Dev 1 will need to pull those changes into her `feature/thing` branch.  Using Git-Flow what's the right approach this this...would she simple "finish" her feature, merging her changes into develop then branching again?  That doesn't seem safe...should she just do a `git pull origin develop` in her branch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working on a feature branch, it is a good idea to merge the `develop` branch into your feature branch regularly, so that you a) know that all will work when you merge back into `develop` and b) can avoid huge merge conflicts. So that is what I would suggest here, for *both* feature branches. That way, if `feature/different-thing` finishes first, the author of `feature/thing` will see that it has broken her work and fix the code accordingly before merging back into `develop`, and visa-versa.

Comment: so you're suggesting just doing a `git merge develop --no-ff` in your branch to keep everything up-to-date.  Sounds good to me.  Thanks @David!

Comment: No need to do a --no-ff for merging develop into the feature branches; you just need to do a --no-ff when merging feature branches into develop.